# Can capybara be used with factory girl and authologic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot, authlogic

I am using authologic in my rails app, while I create user via factory girl and try to login via log form, I can't login(getting issue login is not valid).

Any one having any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post some code, it's hard to say what's going wrong without seeing what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

> Can capybara be used with factory girl and authologic

Yes. There is nothing about factory-girl or authlogic that conflict with capybara

> I am using authologic in my rails app, while I create user via factory girl and try to login via log form, I can't login(getting issue login is not valid). Any one having any suggestion?

Testing login in this way is a pretty typical use case. Hard to say for sure what the problem is (there is a lot that could go wrong) but as you are new to capybara and you are using factory girl i'm guessing its an environment problem.

- If you are using selenium/webkit/poltergeist then your test-code will be running in a different process vs. the app itself. So if you create a user via factory-girl in a before step it wont exist (from apps perspective) when you try to login that user. This is because transaction is isolated. Solution is to disable transactions and use database cleaner to reset test environment.
- Beyond that best suggestion I have is to add `debugger` just above the line that is failing. Then you can have a look at what's in the db via console and see what is going on.